# Most Likely Natural Capabilities of Space Sea Creatures

Tags: biology, creature-design, space, xenobiology

### [SPAAAAAAACE!](https://m.youtube.com/watch?list=PL74Pq21QHYPAnTbaswwEZwoVSlwFJHwev&v=nBwicmhvFs8)

As we all know, space is teeming with life, but as fictive astrobiologists, plausibilifying the exact nature of species is paramount. Hence, take into consideration these species and help me plausify their most noteworthy evolutionary capabilities.

For example, we already know (from the Greek) that Space Sperm Whales are best for precipitating panspermia. Space Frogs are well known to be best at making the jumps to and from hyperspace most efficiently. Space turtles are well suited to traveling to terrestrial planets with dense atmospheres, since their thermally insulated carapaces make them immune to excessive reentry temperatures.

So, with this in mind, help me flesh out exactly what any of my space creatures do better than any other creature:

- Space Squid
- Space Tube Worms
- Space Lion Fish
- Space Cuttlefish
- Space Dolphins (Bottlenose and others)
- Any other space sea creatures that would have distinctive, plot-worthy traits

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49801/discussion-on-question-by-thom-blair-iii-most-likely-natural-capabilities-of-spa).

Answer (score 2):

Tube worms are best at detecting micro wormholes near them, and what is on the other side. When they detect something they want, they extend a tendril that stabilises the wormhole, follow by the main body that expands the tunnel, so they can capture what is on the other size and bring it to home to eat or feed their colony.

Answer (score 1):

- Space Squid is a reliable warrior against other space creatures as well as against space ships
- Space Lion Fish keeps your population of other space animals low and they're pretty much frightening, since they're about 10000 tons.
- Space Cuddle fish is to supply the non animal inhabitants of your world well fed.
- Space Dolphins are used for space fish shows, as they are remarkably intelligent, but not intelligent enough to get away.